# Relationship to multiple children of single table inheritance in NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

**TL.DR.:**

I want to make a single relationship to multiple entities that inherit the same table. To do so, I need to specify the entity that is involved in the relationship and I would like to specify more than one. It seems to me that relationships with multiple types are not possible, even if the types specified inherit the same table. Can it be done, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

**Full description:**

I have the *Task* entity as a base entity. For purposes of this question, I will remove most of the unnecessary columns so it's easier to follow.

```
import { Column, Entity, TableInheritance } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('tasks')
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'type' } })
export class Task {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'bigint' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  name: string;
}
```

And I have the *TaskCollection* and *SpecialTask* entities that inherit the *Task* entity. I want to have a parent-child relationship between them so that only the *TaskCollection* type entities can have children, i.e. *TaskCollection* can have children of both the *TaskCollection* and *SpecialTask* types.

*TaskCollection* entity code:

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { ChildEntity, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';

@ChildEntity('task_collections')
export class TaskCollection extends Task {
 @ManyToOne(
    () => TaskCollection,
    tc => tc.childTasks,
    {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    },
  )
  @Type(() => TaskCollection)
  parentTask: TaskCollection;

  @OneToMany(
    () => TaskCollection | SpecificTask,
    t => t.parentTask,
  )
  @Type(() => TaskCollection | SpecificTask)
  childTasks: (TaskCollection | SpecificTask)[];
}
```

*SpecificTask* entity code:

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { ChildEntity, Column, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';

@ChildEntity('specific_tasks')
export class SpecificTask extends Task {
 @ManyToOne(
    () => TaskCollection,
    tc => tc.childTasks,
    {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    },
  )
  @Type(() => TaskCollection)
  parentTask: TaskCollection;
}
```

[The problem that pop-ups when I try this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzRFx.png)

I would like to avoid changing the *Task* entity because I have more entities that are not associated with this relationship, but I don't know if it's even possible to do something like this.

Any suggestions on how this could be done?